# Rails Model Validation error message is not displayed on the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I am trying to display validation errors in the view. When i try to save this the error is raised both in the view and logs instead with my custom message `additional filter type is required` 
Here is my code

**Model**

```
 class AdditionalFilter < ActiveRecord::Base

 validates :additional_filter_type, presence:{ message: "additional filter type is required" }
 end
```

**View**

```
   <% if @form.errors.any? %>
        <%= @form.errors%>    <!-- i know should just display an array -->
   <%end%>
```

I am using Rails 4. Any help will be appreciated, or even guidance how to debug this.Thank you

Here is the error in the log

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid - Validation failed: Additional filters   additional filter type additional filter type is required:
 activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in   `raise_record_invalid'
 activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `save!`, which raises an exception, which will skip your view entirely. You should be using `save`, and allowing the invalid record to "fall through" to your view.

Comment: Thank you. But i need to save! based on my situation. What would be the alternative to catch the error?

Comment: Then you need to literally *catch the error*. Catch the exception that `save!` raises and let the view be rendered. Otherwise, you need to move your error reporting into a `rescue_from` handler.

Comment: Thank you...Which one is easier and safest? I have heard about `rescue_from` but never used it